# How can I rename master nodes in a HA kubernetes cluster?

Tags: kubernetes, high-availability

I have a kubernetes cluster with 3 master nodes.  They are named master-1, master-2 and master-3.  I would like to rename them as control-plane-n.

I could not find a clear procedure to do this.  The closest one is how to rename a node in a cluster.  So I just tried that.  Here is what I did (my hosts are running ubuntu 18.04, and kubernetes v1.16.2):

On master-1:

- kubectl drain master-3 --ignore-daemonsets
- kubectl delete node master-3
- Run "kubeadm token create --print-join-command" and copy the output

On master-3:

- sudo kubeadm reset
- sudo hostnamectl set-hostname control-plane-3
- Modify /etc/cloud/cloud.cfg to set preserve_hostname to true
- Reboot the VM
- Paste in the join command from master-1, with --control-plane option added

Here is the log I got:

```
sudo kubeadm join 172.22.19.188:6443 --control-plane --token nxxzby.zsfdx86e7cv1rq0e     --discovery-token-ca-cert-hash sha256:553366c2f91fd3abffe3e3d1c39d9314e2d73e8a6181f4da9938a8e24fd77456
[preflight] Running pre-flight checks
    [WARNING IsDockerSystemdCheck]: detected "cgroupfs" as the Docker cgroup driver. The recommended driver is "systemd". Please follow the guide at https://kubernetes.io/docs/setup/cri/
[preflight] Reading configuration from the cluster...
[preflight] FYI: You can look at this config file with 'kubectl -n kube-system get cm kubeadm-config -oyaml'
[preflight] Running pre-flight checks before initializing the new control plane instance
[preflight] Pulling images required for setting up a Kubernetes cluster
[preflight] This might take a minute or two, depending on the speed of your internet connection
[preflight] You can also perform this action in beforehand using 'kubeadm config images pull'
[certs] Using certificateDir folder "/data/kubernetes/pki"
error execution phase control-plane-prepare/certs: error creating PKI assets: failed to write or validate certificate "apiserver": certificate apiserver is invalid: x509: certificate is valid for master-3, kubernetes, kubernetes.default, kubernetes.default.svc, kubernetes.default.svc.cluster.local, not control-plane-3
To see the stack trace of this error execute with --v=5 or higher
```

How can I proceed?  Or is there a better approach?

Thanks in advance for any idea or suggestion you can offer.

Comment: Why wouldn't you instead create 4th node with a proper name, join, then remove one of the old from the cluster. 3 times.

Comment: Are there certs for master-3 in `/data/kubernetes/pki` from before? You might need to do `kubeadm reset --cert-dir xx` to clean them up.

Comment: @zerkms Why not post your suggestion as an answer to help the community?

Comment: I just wasn't sure that could count as an _answer_: it's too many unknowns :shrug:

Comment: I only have 3 master nodes and they were set up by some installation script.  I dont know how to set up 4th node.

Comment: I tried Matt's suggestion.  I ran kubeadm reset --cert-dir to clean up my pki directory.  I then copy the content of the pki directory from master-1 to master-3, and ran the join command again.  But I ended up getting the same error.

Answer (score 0):

Based on @zerkms comment, you can create a 4th node with a proper name, join, then remove one of the old from the cluster.

Doing this 3 times you will be able to have all node with the desired name.